# Magento onepage checkout steps not expanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, checkout

I am having some sort of javascript or jquery conflict with my onepage checkout. None of the steps are expanding. Please have a look at my site here `http://50.87.6.244/~storeupp/index.php/checkout/onepage/`.

Any help to what is causing this issue would be great! I don't know where to start on how to debug the script issue.

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting in your chrome JS console or firebug?

Comment: @R.S I am getting this: `TypeError: registry is undefined
http://50.87.6.244/~storeupp/js/prototype/prototype.js
Line 5557`

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is this is *indeed* a jquery - prototype conflict, just try using jquery.noConflict() where possible. What i always do is i order the js files. First i import all prototype files, put a noConflict file then i import all the jquery files or vice versa. This can avoid alot of problems... If the problem isnt solved after that you can rule out the conflict and start debugging...

Comment: I tried rearranging things but no luck. When I check my console error I see this: `TypeError: registry is undefined
http://50.87.6.244/~storeupp/js/prototype/prototype.js
Line 5557` `TypeError: registry is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

var respondersForEvent = registry.get(eventName);`

Comment: Try to find the function and backtrack the registry variable, this problem will require some debugging...

Comment: Can you provide any further help with this? I am completely stuck. If I remove the jquery script it works but of-course all the jquery breaks on the page. It has to be some sort of conflict but I don't know how to fix it.