# Magento checkout working except for progress boxes

Tags: magento, checkout, progress

I have [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099201/magento-one-page-checkout-getting-typeerror-checkout-undefined-in-opcheckout) been having problems with Magento's one page checkout system.

At the moment it is working in a basic way, but the progress steps which are normally displayed on the right hand side are not being updated when the steps are completed.  The step headings are showing up (Billing Address, Shipping Address, etc.), and I can control their styles through the boxes.css settings, but they don't get filled in with the content as the customer step through the process.

I have tried a number of solutions, including:

[changing the xml](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/130739/#t408264) and
[tweaking the opchecout.js file](http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-checkout-progress-with-custom-layout)

What is the best way to debug something like this?

Comment: Check your checkout by applying default theme.That will give you some idea.

Comment: Thanks, Satish.  I have done that and it works properly with the default theme.

Comment: It means that either one of the modules you have installed has resulted in this or your template code has resulted in this issue.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  But what tools can I use to find out which template files are at fault? (The external modules are the same in both cases).

Comment: Just check if there is any java script error on checkout page.

Comment: Satish: Thanks very much for your continued suggestions.  I have been working on something else for a few days but now I am back on this.  When I open the error console in Firefox, I don't get any errors from the checkout page.  But I am now trying to use Firebug to double-check this.  I am new to Firebug so it may take me a few days to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

check that the ID of the block you insert matches the ID that is refreshed by the JavaScript function. I had that problem. If you are using the base/default/js/opcheckout.js file, it should be

```
id='checkout-progress-wrapper'
```

like so (in your onepage.phtml template):

```
<div id="checkout-progress-wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkoutProgress') ?>
</div>
```

Best if you check the js file also

Comment: I just add id="checkout-progress-wrapper"  on the progress div and this worked for me.